# blocking access to static content folders

Tags: servlets, web.xml

I want to know how to block access to the static content folders in my web-app. right the folders are in inside the web-root folder in the war. like so:

```
    myapp/

       -css/
       -js/
       -swf/
         :
       WEB-INF/
```

I want the content to be visible only from the application when user is in a session. The content should be blocked if someone hits the url outside his/her session (after it has expired).

Its a groovy-grails app with spring and we are using tomcat server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Normally, files under */WEB-INF* are not accessible directly from outside. It is good practise to keep such files under */WEB-INF*.
2. Securing using Web Security constraints. Here is the sample for restricting your folders:

   ```
    <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name >precluded methods</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern >/css/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern >/js/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern >/swf/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint/>
    </security-constraint>
   ```
3. Most of the app servers have the support of masking the files or directories to the outside world. Please check their documentations.

   [Tomcat Documentation](https://serverfault.com/questions/28337/how-to-block-access-to-a-file-from-being-served-by-tomcat)

Comment: Hi, I believe that the above filter specification is to be loaded in to web.xml in the Web-INF folder in the web-app. I was wondering if the web.xml will also work in my development server which is a jetty server , using Netbeans IDE.

Comment: I tried to add the Web Security constraints and its still allowing access, do I need to handle auth-constraint?

Comment: U mean, the jetty serves web.xml? And you want to avoid it?

Comment: I added the above constraints to the web.xml in the tomcat webapps container and its working as expected. now I want to know how do I setup my war building so that this code is automatically appended to the web.xml (currently web.xml gets generated automatically with some default mappings when I give the command grails war). The above code is currently in a web.xml file in my web-app/web-inf folder, when I generate war the web.xml that gets generated doesnot contain the constraints code, I have to unjar and paste it manually.

Comment: Hmm, i do now know which tool you are using for building WAR. Refer to the tool documentation on how to add security constraints and append web.xml

Answer (score 1):

You would need to either:

1. Stream them back yourself after doing a session check
2. Put a regular `Filter` on those paths that check for a valid user in session