# How to deny web access to a Tomcat directory

Tags: tomcat, web, servlets, tomcat7

I've a folder inside my webapp directory.

```
mywebapp/repositoryFolder
```

This webapp is designed to accept a post request with credentials and serve a file in the http response after proper authentication.
I would like to prevent web access to these files.
E.g. Should not be possible to have direct access to a file from the address:

```
http://myserver.com/mywebapp/repositoryFolder/filename.ext
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is good convention to keep such files under WEB-INF. Normally, the files under WEB-INF cannot be accessed by outside world.

But, the other you can achieve this by having this constraint in web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name >precluded methods</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern >/repositoryFolder/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>
```

Also refer this:

[Blocking access to static content folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115132/blocking-access-to-static-content-folders/8120423#8120423)

Comment: Thank you! I'm testing your solution in a few hours. This method does not prevent me from serving the file in an HTTP response handled by my servlet, right?

Comment: @Ramesh PVK - just for completeness - the constraint is missing </security_constraint> at the end

Comment: @DavideLeonardi Correct. It does not prevent you from serving the file via the servlet

Comment: Thanks @gordon613!!

Comment: Hi @RameshPVK, In apache-tomcat 6.0.37, the directory traversal vulnerability with the URL http://localhost/../manager/html, but when there is a semicolon followed by 2 dots, we can able to access tomcat directories as http://localhost/..;/manager/html, how can we avoid the pattern /..;/ , due to this url pattern the the request redirects to tomcat internal folders instead of redirecting to servlet application in webapps folder, please suggest.